# Open Facebook Login popup as modal popup

Tags: facebook, authentication, modalpopup

We are using facebook api, to open facebook log in popup, but instead we need to open facebook login popup as modal popup.

Can on please let us know how to open facebook login as modal popup?

Answer (score 0):

How about using [JQuery's dialog widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/)? You can show it with a message saying "waiting for login" and then hide it when the log in is successful?